# Google Sheet Query: how to calculate factored average?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

| aritcle_id | hit | average_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 180 |
| 1 | 4 | 20 |
| 2 | 1 | 11 |
| 3 | 22 | 33 |
| 4 | 55 | 11 |

I want to calculate the average_time and total hit on each article.

```
=QUERY(A:C,"SELECT A,SUM(B),AVG(C) GROUP BY A")
```

wont't do the job, because when calculating average time you have to take hit into consideration. How should I modify the formula?

P.S. the average time for article #1 should be 180x2 + 20x4 / 2+4 = 73.33

Comment: Can you maybe add in expected result (manually done) for this sample dataset?!

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach (it `aint query` based by the way)

```
=byrow(unique(filter(A2:A,A2:A<>"")),lambda(z,{z,round(average.weighted(filter(C:C,A:A=z),filter(B:B,A:A=z)),2)}))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It works for me. But I'd like to know if there is a way to do this in Query. I think this can be done in Mysql, and google sheet should have something equivalent.... or not..

Comment: hoping someone else would pitch in with a way to do it via `query` if feasible.